# R and SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, r

Is there a way to use `R` power in `SQL Server 2008?`, I mean use in console or communicate both of them.
If it is What would be the procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SQL Server Data Within R:**

An example using SQL Server data within R is [here](http://blog.sqltrainer.com/2011/12/statistical-analysis-with-r-and.html). This blog post deals with plotting data from a SQL server table using K-Means Clustering.

**Calling R within SQL Server:**

You can use the extended Stored Procedure [XP_CmdShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to call R (or any command line tool as Nick points out) within SQL Server.

*Enable Functionality In Server Level:*

XP_CmdShell exposes the cmd shell within SQL Server. For obvious reasons, this is not    enabled by default. A SysAdmin (or someone with Control Server permission) can [enable](http://stefanzvonar.com/2011/11/18/executing-xp_cmdshell-with-sql-server-2008-r2/) this functionality in server level.

*Enable a specific User to Access this functionality:*

```
 exec ON xp_cmdshell TO *YourLoginHere*
```

Refer [this URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more info on best practices  (such as using a proxy account for non-SysAdmin users) and example usage.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the RODBC package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/.

Vignette is [here](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/bdr/RODBC-manual.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I think RODBC does the reverse of what you ask (I think you want to call R from within SQL Server). However, from stored procedures in SQL Server, and with the correct security settings (you probably want to talk to a highly skilled sysadmin here), you can run any command line tool, including R. I remember there being a system stored procedure for that (but forgot its name since it's been a while).

You could pass a script (maybe even a scripted script) to R, or pass it the right information to connect to the SQL Server again via RODBC, where it could find a table with statements to execute or data to use for analysis.

That should give you enough power to communicate both ways...