# Can we run r script from SQL Server 2008

Tags: r, sql-server-2008

I want to run R script from SQL Server 2008. I don't want to use RODBC package in R to get data from SQL Server. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Please show you research and what you have tried. Check out this as a starting point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591996.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initiate an R script from SQL Server 2008. That's described in the following post:

[Run R script from SQL Server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784960/r-and-sql-server-2008)

However, I believe you are trying to perform an operation in R on the data that's stored in the database. You cannot do that directly in SQL Server 2008. This is a feature in the upcoming SQL Server 2016 edition. A Google search will give you much more detail than I can.

An RODBC connection might be one of the few options you have. There are packages like **dplyr** that make the ETL process from SQL Server much more intuitive than writing plain SQL statements, so I recommend it. [RSQLServer package](https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Alek, it was really helpful .